# Error -Cannot recognize package: go.opencensus.io While build datacollector-edge

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, streamsets, opencensus

I have created directory $GOPATH/src/github.com/streamsets . Then cloned https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge.git into it. When I run './gradlew goClean dist publishToMavenLocal', after resolving many dependencies I get the below error.

Task :resolveBuildDependencies FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':resolveBuildDependencies'.
Exception in resolution, message is: Cannot recognize package: go.opencensus.io Resolution stack is: +- github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge
I am trying to resolve dependencies behind company proxy. Please help me with this

Thanks,
Aleena

Answer (score 0):

```
When I installed Go, the above error got resolved and got a new error as below.
Execution failed for task ':resolveBuildDependencies'.
> Exception in resolution, message is:
  Cannot recognize package: pack.ag/amqp
  Resolution stack is:
  +- github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge

Once I downloaded and copied pack.ag/amqp package in /user/.gradle/go/repo/ and I ran the command 
'./gradlew goClean dist publishToMavenLocal', I got go4.org error as below.
Cannot recognize package: go4.org/syncutil/singleflight
  Resolution stack is:
  +- github.com/streamsets/datacollector-edge
   +- github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#adca289fdcf8c883800aafa545bc263452290bae
    +- golang.org/x/net#5f4716e94777e714bc2fb3e3a44599cb40817aac

Anyone got any idea about this?

Thanks again.
```